# no children selection

Tags: jquery, for-loop, each, children

I have some htmls, where some  tags does not have any children, and I want to identify them and count the number of those  tags.

I have tried the following and it doesn't seem to work:

```
var count = 0;
$("th[class=gridlabel]").each(function(){
if($("th[class=gridlabel]").children().length<1)
 {
count++;
 }
});
return count;
alert(count);
```

not sure what's the issue here.

---

I have added some additional scripts from the html source code, I want to ensure the "count" will only count the first two  tags, for "answer 3" and "answer 4", as their  tags do not have children:

```
  <tr>
    <th class="gridlabel">answer 3</th>
    <td headers="q12_header1" class="gridcell"><input><div><span>answer 3</span><label>1</label></div></td>
    <td headers="q12_header2" class="gridcell"><input><div><label></label></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="gridlabel">answer 4</th>
    <td headers="q12_header1" class="gridcell"><input><div><span>answer 4</span><label>1</label></div></td>
    <td headers="q12_header2" class="gridcell"><input><div><label></label></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="gridlabel">other specify 1<input><label>other specify 1</label></th>
    <td><input><div><span>other specify 1</span><label>1</label></div></td>
    <td><input><div><label>2</label></div></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var count = $("th.gridlabel:empty").length;
return count;
```

**Update**

Given the HTML you provided, you could use something like this if you know that "non-empty" cells will have an input child :

```
var count = $('th:not(:has(input))').length;
```

If you want something a little more flexible, but a little longer, you can do something like :

```
var count = 0;
$('th').each(function(){
    if($(this).children().length < 1)
    {
        count++;
    }
})
```

That way you'll cover any possible child tag. It really depends on what you need.

Comment: Thanks Leo, it doesn't seem to work neither, here is part of the html:

Comment: I think your html copy/paste didn't work here. You should edit the question itself.

Comment: Many thanks Leo, it's working perfectly now. the removal of "return count;" has allowed the alert message to come up. not sure if you could let me know when to use "return"? it seems negligible in some ways.

Comment: Every code you place *after* a return call in a function will not be executed. You'll want to use return when you want the result of a function to be stocked in a variable, per exemple. Like `var abc = function(){ return 1+2 }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var count = 0;
$("th[class=gridlabel]").each(function(){
    if(this.children().length<1)
    {
        count++;
    }
});
return count;
alert(count);
```